# Solve differential equation given $y=1$ where, $x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $$\frac{dy}{dx} = y + \int_0^1 y\,\mathrm dx$$
given y=1, where x=0

Cannnot figure out what to do with $\int y\,\mathrm dx$

Comment: yeah, i forgot to put in question

Comment: What i mean is we need to find out y as a function of x by integration and the values are given to find constant of integration

Comment: Corrected it :)

Comment: This is a non-local ode.

Comment: What is a non local ODE. We have just started this chapter and i had this problem in my assignment

Comment: Ok if you just started the topic it should be unlikely that they want you to solve a nonlocal ODE (derivative depends not on local data but rather on the data on the interval between 0 an 1). Solving nonlocal ODEs is not trivial at all. Sometimes you can choose a clever ansatz. You should check the assignement if you copied it correctly.

Comment: yeah i did. I dont know. Ill post the solution if they tell how to do this

Answer (score 2):

You can differentiate the ODE to get

$$y’’ = y’\implies y = a+be^x.$$

Note, that the integral is a constant value hence is zero after differentiating.

**Explanation for solution of implied ODE**: To solve the implied ODE we use Euler’s exponential ansatz $y=e^{\lambda x}$ to obtain $0=y’’-y’=(\lambda^2-\lambda)e^{\lambda x}$. As the exponential function is non-zero we have to set $\lambda^2-\lambda=0$. The solutions are $\lambda_1=0$ and $\lambda_2= 1$. Hence the general solution of the implied ODE is:

$$ y=ae^{\lambda_1 x}+be^{\lambda_2 x}=a+be^x.$$

Plug this into the ODE and you will get a relationship for $a$ and $b$:

$$be^x=a+be^x+a+b(e^1-e^0) \implies 0 =2a+b(e-1).$$

Then use $y(0)=1 \implies 1=a+b\implies 2=2a+2b.$

Subtract both equations to obtain: $-2=b(e-3)\implies b = \frac{2}{3-e}$. Then use $1=a+b\implies a=1-b=1-\frac{2}{3-e}$ to finally obtain the second coefficient.

I don’t know if the solution is unique.

Comment: How did you judge that y would be of that particular type

Comment: The eigenvalues by Euler’s exponential ansatz are $\lambda_1=0$ and $\lambda_2=1$. Hence, $y=ae^{0 \cdot x}+be^{1 \cdot x}$.

Comment: Sorry if my explanations are only short I am using my phone to type :D.

Comment: Ill probably read this from a book haha. I need to start from basics

Comment: much appreciated man :)

Comment: I added more details.

Comment: Yeah i get some things, ive seen these things on youtube. Thankyou so muchh

Comment: Hi, my teacher did this in interesting way, he said integral ydx is constant so let it be k for a moment and do integration and after that he calculated y as a function of x and put it in ydx to get answer